# How do i change the look of my android preferences?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences

Im having a couple of issues with my android preferences. Firstly i want a line divider/horizontal rule below my `PreferenceCategory` (Accounts), which in the preferences tutorial seems to automatically be placed under category headings, but in my case has not. Another issue is i would like to change the color of my preference title's (Add Account and Remove Account). At the moment they seem to be getting colored via my `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>` located in my `style.xml`, which i cannot change as i want the Settings title to remain white. Below is an image of where i currently am:

[image: Screenshot of preferences]

If anybody could advise me on resolving these issue's it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other UI aspect of `Android`, you can customize it using a custom XML file. Just create a new layout (ex. custom_preference) and just set that in your `Preference`:

```
<Preference
android:title="@string/label_pref_version"
android:key="@string/pref_version"
android:layout="@layout/custom_preference" />
```

Comment: How would i define the color of my `android:title` and `android:summary` using a custom layout file?

Comment: You can utilize: `android:textColorSecondary` which would be in your `style.xml`

Comment: Sorry im slightly lost. So inside my `custom_preference` layout i would have `android:textColorSecondary`? I already have that in my  `style.xml `, which defines it for the entire app?

Comment: If you just want to change the color of your text you can set the `android:textColorPrimary` (which you already said you did) and the `android:textColorSecondary` both in you `style.xml`. The secondary should change the other text colors. Or you can just do everything (text color, lines, other styles) in a separate layout

Comment: When i change `android:textColorPrimary` it changes the title of the preference, which i want, but it also changes the `Settings` heading on the action bar, which i don't want. I would also like to have icons next to my preferences, but i am struggling to get this level of customisation

Comment: In that case, just create you own layout. I would just use a `ListView`, and then you can add icons, or whatever else you want to each list item.

Comment: If i use the code from your original post, will the listview not just be used in place of that single preference, rather then the listview replacing the entire preferences screen?

Comment: Your `custom_preference.xml` (or whatever you want to call it) can really have any layout/views you want. I would just suggest a `LinearLayout` with a `ListView` to contain your settings. Although now that I think of it if you don't have that many items maybe just basic components (`TextViews` ect) might be easier to use and handle. Still within a `LinearLayout` though.

Comment: Ok so in my preferences xml i only need to define a single preference, and assign a custom xml layout which will actually be a list of all my preferences? also will this be able to handle preference sub-screens? i would like to embed a facebook login button on a subscreen

Comment: Yes, you would need to add custom code in your java classes. For example, if you click on an item in that layout you would need a click listener to either create a dialog or redirect to a new screen (which would in turn be it's own layout)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69669/discussion-between-dom-shahbazi-and-ryan-sayles).